# Why does Eclipse mark interface methods public abstract?

Tags: java, eclipse, interface

When using Eclipse's "*Extract Interface*" refactoring, it will declare the methods `public abstract` by default. Why? `public` modifier on an interface is completely redundant and `abstract` also seems meaningless on an interface declaration.

Comment: Uncheck `Declare interface methods as public` and `Declare interface methods as abstract` checkboxes? I believe these can be useful to simplify converting interface into abstract class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These keywords are indeed redundant. I personally wouldn't use them in this context, but I can see why someone might prefer to include them.

The JLS [explicitly discourages](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4) this practice:

> It is permitted, but discouraged as a matter of style, to redundantly specify the `public` and/or `abstract` modifier for a method declared in an interface.

In my version of Eclipse (Juno SR1), there are two options in the Extract Interface dialog:

- declare interface methods as `public`;
- declare interface methods as `abstract`.

If you untick them, Eclipse should no longer include the two keywords when you extract an interface.

There is a pending [Eclipse bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=130888) to clean up the redundant modifies.

Comment: Yes, and by default they are both selected which made me wonder why? As far as I know they just add redundant clutter to the interface declarations. If you can see why someone might prefer to include them, can you elaborate on it?

Comment: I too have those options, but they are selected by default, and are non-editable.

Comment: @Rohit, you should pick a few methods first to enable them

Comment: @vertti: They do, and the JLS discourages their use in this manner. See the quote I've added to the answer.

Comment: @denis.solonenko.. Oh yes. I used it on a class without any method previously, so didn't see that option.

Comment: @NPE and checkstyle / Sonar etc complain about these so it seems like a strange decision in Eclipse.

Comment: @vertti: I've no idea how Eclipse's default behaviour came about, but here is a relevant bug report: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=71627

Comment: @NPE add "it's a bug/pending enhancement in Eclipse" to your answer and I'll accept it.